# ADF application hangs for some time

Tags: java, oracle, swing, oracle-adf

In my oracle ADF application a JTable is added to a panel in which the data appears after some time with a pause of 6 seconds. When I look at the log output of `dJBo` it shows the following logs:

```
[6024] (47) PCollNode.checkForSplit(1597) $$added root$$ id=-2
[6025] (1108) PCollNode.checkForSplit(1597) $$added root$$ id=-73
```

when these logs appears it takes time. What are these logs? How can I avoid this?

Comment: Wow, you are the first person I've heard of using ADF with Swing. Not sure how mature this technology glue really is.

Comment: @FlorinMarcus do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Absolutely none, sorry.

Comment: did you ever find out what it was? I'm running into this situation?

Comment: I didn't remember is exactly.. but it was something related to ViewLink which was causing ViewObject to execute query multiple times. btw do you get the same logs? What exactly are you using? @asgs

Comment: Yeah, I get the same logs. But I don't have a ViewLink here. It's just a SQL-based VO

Comment: I am getting the same: <PCollNode> <checkForSplit> [16408] $$added root$$ id=-2
<PCollNode> <checkForSplit> [16409] $$added root$$ id=-73 but with a lot of hanging time . . .

Comment: @asgs So how did you solve it?

Comment: @GingerHead I don't remember solving it. (Un)Fortunately, I don't work on ADF projects any more